# Display 'Full-month-name yyyy' with eyecon bootstrap datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I'm trying to display full month name like 'January 2014' with eyecon Bootstrap datepicker http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/  Does anybody know if it's possible? I've tried everything I know (I'm a junior in JS).

Comment: yes it prints like that.The 1st example shows like that January 2012 when clicked on the 1st text field

Comment: I think OP wants to display full month in textfield after selecting date. S/He is not asking about datepicker itself.

Comment: @MysticMagic indeed that's the behavior I'm looking for. I've configured the actual datepicker to let me select only months. but the displaying style I'm looking for is 'January 2014'. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I know this is little old thread. But I came across this when I was searching for similar behavior. As I couldn't find such feature natively, patched some code snippets to get that work.

http://jsfiddle.net/saz52h11/

The changes are:

```
var monthnames = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
----
case 'mmm':
date.setMonth(monthnames.indexOf(val));
----
mmm:monthnames[date.getMonth()]
----
val.mmm = monthnames[val.m-1];
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

This works fine:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker( {
    format: "MMMM YYYY",
    startView: 1, 
    minViewMode: 1
});
```

Change the format field to 'MMMM' instead of 'mm' and it will provide full month. If you use "MMM" it will show the three character abreviation for the month.

Comment: for newer version it seems that MM is full name and M is abr

Comment: As of 2018 change the format to format: "MM yyyy" to get the appropriate result

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker( {
    format: "mm-yyyy",
    viewMode: "months", 
    minViewMode: "months"
});
```

also notice that in the version of 1.2.0 the `viewMode` has changed to `startView`.

Update:

**[Refer This Demo](http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/)**

Comment: I've played around with those options: viewMode and minViewMode, refer to the actual date picker, and format is the one that formats the date in the <input>. My problem is that I can't find a format to look like "January 2014" or "Jan 2014". It converts them all to digit

Comment: @AndreiDoanca:Still not sure what you are trying to do.

Comment: after selecting a month in the date picker, the <input> field that gets populated  must look like "January 2014" instead of "01-2014", unfortunately this date picker from eyecon doesn't have an format like  that, and I must do some coding...unfortunately I'm a junior in JS...anyways: the format that I'm looking for is "Mon yyyy"

Comment: @AndreiDoanca:see the demo from above link. you will find the code for implementation too.

Comment: @AndreiDoanca:also make the habbit of accepting answers that helps you.

Comment: thanks for the link, I see that this one has what I'm loooking for. Does this mean that I must use this source code?

Comment: I do accept them :) I might answered short but with no offense intended

Comment: @AndreiDoanca:yes you have to refer that code.play around with demo for any more changes you are looking for.